# display: inline-block; issue on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have with inline-block property in Firefox and probably in IE also. I am expecting the same result as I am getting in Chrome.

Chrome desktop screenshot

[image]

Chrome and Firefox tablet (I have to keep "A" and "BC" together in tablet view)

[image]

Here is a problem with Firefox desktop view. As you can see E is not visible in screenshot. I google it but did not find the solution. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f5t42key/3/)

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="text-center">
    <div class="text">
        <div class="col-first">A</div>
        <div class="col-last">
            <ul class="links">
                <li>B</li>
                <li>C</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-middle">
            <ul>
                <li>C</li>
                <li>D</li>
                <li>E</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul{ margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none}

.text-center{text-align:center}
.text{ display:inline-block}
.col-first {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.col-last {
    float: right;
}

.col-middle {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.social li{float:left}
.col-middle li{ display:inline-block; padding:0 17px}

@media(max-width:768px){
    .col-first {float:none;display:inline-block; padding-right:10px; vertical-align:top}
    .col-last {float:none;display:inline-block}
    .col-middle { width:100%}
}
```

Comment: This would appear to be the _"white space"_ problem associated with `display: inline-block;`. See [this reference](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for more information...

Comment: Your fiddle is not the same as your HTML source. Anyway, I don't see any difference in behaviour between the two browsers with the fiddle.

Comment: @MrLister: here you can see the difference https://jsfiddle.net/f5t42key/5/embedded/result/

Comment: @amit That's strange; if you start out on a narrow window with Chrome, and then make the window wider, the E goes missing. But if you start out with a wide window, the E is there. Very odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what is going on if you mess around with  column width.

Essentially,  is being created by the browser at one width (in my case:142px and the content inside of that div works out to be about 182px), so the browser is "tucking the E off of the page" because it won't fit in the space allotted for it.

This div size issue is caused because the size of div is determined when chrome loads, and is not checked again by chrome.  You can see this by making your chrome width very large(zoom way out with the browsers functionality) and then refresh the browser.  Your e will appear as desired, but if you make your browser narrower, and the wider again, the media query will reset the size of that div, and it will not get set back making the div disappear.

You can fix this by setting the width of  to be greater(or equal to) using a relative width(eg .text{ display:inline-block;width:30%;}) or changing the list structure.